# how to show loading in percent, while loading from src folder

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pdf, state, loader

I am working on a pdf reader in my reactJS app. I need to show the loading indicator of a pdf file. My pdf reader only loads once the file is completely loaded. As you can see in [this link](http://balpaathmala.olenepal.org/books/read/c0286efe-adf5-49de-ad89-e94ddbc67a66).

I think loading the pdf file separately first while showing the loading percent indicator and then only loading the pdf loader component would do the trick.

Also a useState to set loaded state and loaded percent would probably be a good idea to go about it. Please help me implement this and feel free to suggest anything else.

My current code for this is as follows:

```
import PDFViewer from "mgr-pdf-viewer-react"

function Reader({ bookDetail }) {
    const readerRef = useRef(null)

    return (
        bookDetail !== null && (
            //  ...
                <PDFViewer
                    page={1}
                    document={{
                        url: bookDetail.bookUrl,
                    }}
                />
            // ...
        )
    )
}

export default Reader
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no straight forward way to show progress % with `mgr-pdf-viewer-react`. So you have to kind off do your own.

- Use a `ref` and attach it to `PDF` component. The library maintains a state called `pages` which is set after pdf document is loaded. Read the `pages` value using the `ref` and show progress bar until pages has got some value.

Use some library for progress bar. I have used [react-progressbar](https://github.com/abdennour/react-progressbar)

[Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/pdf-loading-placeholder-lb7eh?file=/src/App.js)

```js
import PDFViewer from "mgr-pdf-viewer-react";
import ProgressBar from "react-progressbar";

export default function App() {
  const [currentProgress, setCurrentProgress] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    progress();
  }, []);

  const ref = useRef(null);

  const progress = () => {
    let step = 5; // the smaller this is the slower the progress bar
    let current_progress = 0;
    const interval = setInterval(function() {
      current_progress += step;
      setCurrentProgress(current_progress);
      let progress =
        Math.round((Math.atan(current_progress) / (Math.PI / 2)) * 100 * 1000) /
        1000;

      // console.log(ref.current);
      if (ref.current && ref.current.state.pages) {
        console.log("cleared");
        current_progress = 100;
        setCurrentProgress(current_progress);
        clearInterval(interval);
      } else if (progress >= 70) {
        step = 0.1;
      }
    }, 100);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <p>{currentProgress + " %"}</p>
      {<ProgressBar completed={currentProgress} />}
      <PDFViewer
        ref={ref}
        document={{
          url: "https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0410100.pdf"
        }}
        // loader={<h2 style={{ color: "#fa5b35" }}>Custom loader element</h2>}
        // loader={<ProgressBar completed={currentProgress} />}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. It does work. But still is there a better way, maybe without using `mgr-pdf-viewer-react`, I am open to using another reader no problem.